# How do I make a readonly mirror of my github repo?

Tags: version-control, github

We need to have a read only github repo that mirrors our main branch.

I've noticed castle have managed to do it with their entire collection of repositories.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Castleproject is an [organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) (also [mentioned here](https://github.com/features/projects)) in order to restrict write access.
That is why you see read-only addresses on their projects.

That also means it (ie the organization "castleproject") can add users with read-only rights.
As a simple user owning a GitHub repo, you wouldn't have access to that feature.
You need to define an "organization".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for right here:

http://justcramer.com/2011/05/09/creating-a-one-way-git-server-mirror/

Comment: i found this but it means running a job every minute from a server or something